# create a 24*30 matrix from a 100*30 matrix excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I have looked up for this and I didn't found anything that suits to my problem.

So, I have a 100*30 matrix and I want to make the average of the first 4 elements in the first row, then the average of the next for elements in the first row and so on.

From this, I'll have a 24*30 matrix. I've done that, but mt log paste the results spaced by 4 elements.

How can I create the matrix all together ?

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim media_horaria As Long
    Dim hora As Long

    media_horaria = 0
    hora = 0

    With Sheets("Folha1")
        For i = 28 To 58
            For j = 3 To 100 Step 3
                hora = Cells(i, j).Value + Cells(i, j + 1).Value + Cells(i, j + 2).Value + Cells(i, j + 3).Value
                media_horaria = hora / 4
                Cells(i + 45, j).Value = media_horaria
            Next j

            media_horaria = 0
            hora = 0

        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

With the result matrix, I would like to create a colour map depending on the cell value. For instance, if the cell value is under 0.5 and above 0.45 paint in light red. If the cell is above 0.50 and under 0.55 paint in dark red. With the legend under the matrix. Top level will be having a picture.

Comment: I'm unclear on why your `For j =3 to 100` uses `Step 3` as an increment when you are averaging 4 values but storing the value could be changed to `Cells(i + 45, Int(j/3)+3).Value = media_horaria` to tighten up the results.

Comment: Because I need the average of the elements 1 2 3 4 of the first row, then the elements 5 6 7 8 of the first row and so on.

By the way, you have resolve my issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: A quick success story is always good to hear. I was just worried that you are averaging 1 2 3 4, then 4 5 6 7, then 7 8 9 10. If you've checked the results and they are correct then I'll take another look tomorrow to see where I am thinking wrong.

Comment: yes, the result matrix is absolutely what I wanted. Now I am dealing with other stuff. I don't know if you guys can help me. With the result matrix, I would like to create a colour map depending on the cell value. For instance, if the cell value is under 0.5 and above 0.45 paint in light red. If the cell is above 0.50 and under 0.55 paint in dark red. With the legend under the matrix.

Top level will be having a picture. 
If you guys have some ideia on how to start with this I'll be grateful

Comment: see [Conditional Formatting -- Introduction](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html). The legend could be manually 'painted' or have it's cells added to the `Applies to:` of the CF rule.

Comment: Do you think in VBA it will be difficult to implement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet for creating the Conditional Formatting Rules could fit into your existing sub or run from another.

```
With Sheets("Folha1").Cells(73, 3).Resize(31, 33)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC>=0.45,RC<0.5)"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC>=0.5, RC<0.55)"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ColorIndex = 9
    End With
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(2, 1) = "Legend"
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(3, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(3, 1) = ChrW(8805) & "0.45 And <0.5"
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(4, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 9
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(4, 1) = ChrW(8805) & "0.5 And <0.55"
End With
```

The row and column references may have to be adjusted slightly according to where your final data resides. If you are unhappy with the color choices, record a macro of setting cell colors and use those `.Color =` instead of the limited palette of the `.ColorIndex =`.

Comment: Awesome Jeeped. Thank you very much. I only needed to change this two lines:
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC>=0.45,RC<0.5)"

    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC>=0.5, RC<0.55)"

But I've created a macro and see the code and then replace this two lines with:
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=0.5"

Thanks you